# geodesics on a compact manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, closed-geodesic

Let $M$ be a compact Riemann manifold without boundary. Please is this true that each homotopy class of closed curves contains a  geodesic?

Comment: Each non-trivial free homotopy class.

Comment: And even the trivial class (constant maps are closed geodesics).

Comment: This is more appropriate for MathStackExchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably this is a reference request (since the statement is sort of well-known).

See Theorem IV.5.1 in

*Chavel, Isaac*, Riemannian geometry. A modern introduction, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics 98. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 0-521-61954-8/pbk; 0-521-85368-0/hbk). xvi, 471 p. (2006). [ZBL1099.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1099.53001).